# linq to sql where clause and counting

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a linq-to-sql query that I use to fill an object that has ints as properties and whose function is to hold counts.

The query looks like this (for now)

```
var TheQuery = from.....
               where ....
               in thefilteredresults
               select new MyModel()
               {
                   Total = thefilteredresults.Count(),

                   TotalTime = (from x in thefilteredresults
                                where x.Outcome == 4).Sum(t => t)
               }.Single();
```

I'm have some problem filtering first and then counting based on the filtered results of the initial where clauses.
What do I need to modify?

Thanks.

Comment: Where does thefilteredresults come from, and what does it look like?

Comment: filteredresult is the result of the from and where clauses; I'm filtereing by userID and datetime and then doing the counts only on those records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hack this together:

```
(from x in table
where filter(x)
group x by 0 into g
select new { Count = (int?)g.Count() ?? 0, Sum = (int?)g.Sum(x => x.Value) ?? 0 }).Single()
```

SQL Server will optimize out the unneeded grouping. It is probably best do document why you wrote it like this.

Edit: I included a strange-looking cast to int?. The reason for this is to tell Linq to SQL to assume that the value is nullable and to use a COALELCE function call to convert the NULL to 0. This is a hack that should be documented, too.

Comment: Just to clarify: This solution will do a single round-trip to the database. It will be more efficient than to do two queries.

Comment: I like the concept. Since I'm filtering by UserID in the where clause, I rewrote the group clause "group x by x.UserID into g" and that works. Now the problem I'm having is that sometimes the group is empty and so the count returns null and the query crashes. How do I say "get the count or get 0 if there's nothing?"

Comment: For performance reasons I recommend you really group by "0". I don't know if SQL Server can optimize out the unneeded group-by-UserID.

Comment: yea, this is really clever; I like the (int?) casting way. Thanks a lot, learned something new with the groupby 0.

Comment: I *don't* like this ;-) Alas, it is necessary. L2S is still more productive than raw SQL.

Comment: +1: That is a neat trick for consolidating things into a single round-trip. I'll have to remember that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're really only looking for one result, this is probably the simplest approach:

```
var filteredResults = from ....
                      where ....
                      select ....;
var myModel = new MyModel{ Total = filteredResults.Count(), ... };
```

Comment: Thanks, I see how this could work by bringing all the records from the db and then doing the aggregation in linq-to-objects. I was wondering if there's also a way to do it in linq-to-sql, without having to bring back all the results from the db.

Comment: @frenchie: You aren't actually bringing everything into memory and counting from there, it's lazy loaded.

Comment: I don't see what is lazyly loaded here. If it was it would be even worse: It would cause a SELECT N+1 problem.

Comment: @frenchie: The code I posted is assuming you're using linq-to-sql. Note the absence of "ToList". The call to "Count" will do a database round-trip which just returns a single "Count" value. usr's approach has the advantage of performing a single round-trip for both the Count and the Sum, whereas my approach will use a separate round-trip for each. On the other hand, mine will produce a simpler query which is easier for the LINQ-to-SQL engine to translate and materialize.

Comment: @usr `var filteredResults` is still `IQueryable` which means that an  operation like `filteredResults.Count()` will be translated into SQL and executed on the SQL server.

Comment: @Magnus: I think usr is pointing out that there's a difference between lazy *loading* and lazy *evaluation*.